# PHP vs Java: Using Beans

Tags: java, php, database, javabeans

I am a Java programmer and when we retrieve data from a database, we normally create a "`Bean`". Then using the `setters` of this bean, we will up the data into it, and pass it to other places.

Now, I am making a PHP application where I need to retrieve, insert data into a database. I know how to do it in the normal way, catch the HTML form information and pass it into a PHP file. I am wondering whether PHP also uses these `Beans`and if it is, how to do it? My google search told me it is not common in PHP to use a `Bean` ?

Comment: "Bean" is a Java-centric name (think of Java coffee and thus coffee beans) and hence you'd need to translate that into a more general context. Basically a bean is an object with defined characteristics for getters and setters and if the language supports objects you should be able to mimick that.

Comment: @Thomas: OK, then PHP getters and setters?

Comment: I'd say PHP _objects_ (you could use getters/setters or properties, depending on what's supported). Just keep in mind that this would be a Java way of thinking and PHP might have different best practices.

Comment: @Thomas:hmm.. Yeah..

Comment: if you are trying to implement MVC like (Spring) in PHP you can go with different php frameworks like laravel, Symphony etc.

Comment: Have a look at [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), it provides the way you looking for.